# Clearing a specific shape in canvas with pixel accurcy

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to add a shape to canvas and then clearing it without using clearRect, and here is a demonstration

```js
const canvas  = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.height = 300
canvas.width = 300
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

const make = () => {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(50, 50);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(100, 75, 100, 100);
 ctx.arc(75, 100, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
    ctx.lineWidth = 1
 ctx.stroke()
}

const draw = () => {
 make()
}

const clear = () => {
 ctx.save()
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
 make()
 ctx.restore()
}

draw()
clear()
```

as you can notice the shape doesn't get cleared as exoected it just gets lighter and some pixels are not removed,
the problem is shapes are relatively complex and I can't use clearRect , and the only solution I've found is increasing the linewidth when clearing, but its more of a hack, any idea how to resolve this neatly, is it because of antialiasing?

Comment: Yes it's because of antialiasing. gCO works with the alpha channel, antaliasing creates artifacts with lower alpha. Not too much you can do apart from clearing and redrawing everything. Also remember that you can have offscreen canvases, which will help you with complex composition, thanks to the layer strategy it offers. (drawBGcanvas, if (needed) drawMiddleCanvas, drawFGCanvas)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the info, i ended up creating layers where each layer is a separate canvas then increasing the original linewidth by 1.5 when clearing, this make is more flexible than a single canvas